# How to get project on the source control in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

In fact, i am well connected to the project in azure devops, and i have all the drotis and permissions.

but when I click on the Source Control Explorer (on the right), and I have the project path in azure devops (on the left), I did not get the project? and the Local Path still Not Mapped?

for I am well connected to azure devops and I have all rights.

here is screenshot of the problem:

!(https://ibb.co/GQFJbVR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you may enter the wrong url or not select a project to connect.

In Azure DevOps service, there is **no need to add any collection in the url**, an organization is just kind of a collection--defaultcollection. So you shouldn't add collection name when you try to connect in Team Explorer.

As you can see, it's **connect to a project**. Please select a team project during the drop down list.

[image]

After you connected to a team project in Azure DevOps service, you should be able to see something as below

[image]

There is an arrow, after click it, you will be able to see all projects which you have permission to access. And projects already mapped will be black. You could directly get latest and download files from source control. More detail steps please follow our official tutorial here-- [Download (get) files from the Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server?view=azure-devops)

Otherwise, you need to first map with your local folders, then get source later.